# FFMPEG Invalid Option

Tags: powershell, video, ffmpeg

Per the suggestion from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) I have shortened the output here to just the relevant code and error.  Additionally, as he pointed out, I have changed how I am constructing the arguments (*now passing as an array*).

Additionally, the comment from [kesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4516027/kesh), I removed the "-filter_complex" and changed to just several "-map" 's.

```
$TEMPDIR = "E:\MediaConversions\BitLadder"
$FOLDER = 'White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO'
$OUTPUTDIR = $TEMPDIR + '\' + $FOLDER

# Mux the 8 Bitrate Ladder steps into a single file, with a common audio stream
$STEPS = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $OUTPUTDIR -Name)
$INPUT_FILES = @()
$MAP = @()
$COUNT = 0
ForEach ($STEP in $STEPS){
    $INPUT_FILES += ('-i', "$STEP")
    $MAP += ('-map ' + "$COUNT" + ':v', '-map ' + "$COUNT" + ':a') 
    $COUNT++
}

$OPTIONS = ('-' + "$INPUT_FILES", "$MAP")
#$OPTIONS
D:\Applications\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe "$OPTIONS" -f matroska "E:\MediaConversions\White.Boy.Rick.2018_MultiStreamTest_AAC.H264.mkv"
```

But Sadly, I still get the same frustrating error:

```
Unrecognized option '-i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP1.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP2.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP3.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP4.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP5.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP6.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP7.mp4 -i White.Boy.Rick.2018.1080p.WEB-DL.H264.AC3-EVO_STEP8.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:v -map 1:a -map 2:v -map 2:a -map 3:v -map 3:a -map 4:v -map 4:a -map 5:v -map 5:a -map 6:v 
-map 6:a -map 7:v -map 7:a'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: That's a lot of information and code to go through. One thing to note: In order to programmatically pass arguments to external programs, construct an _array_, with each parameter (option) name and parameter value / positional argument (operand) becoming its own element. E.g., to execute `foo -o "bar baz"`, use `$a = '-o', 'bar baz'; foo $a`

Comment: The problem I pointed out in my previous comment persists in your updated question. You need to create a flat array of tokens, with each option name and value becoming its own element, as demonstrated in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `-complex_filter` just to map input streams to output file. You just need to use `-map` as many times as you have streams:

```
... -map 0:v -map 1:v ... -map 0:a -map 1:a ...
```